# How to add submodule correctly with non-standard refspec?

Tags: git, gerrit, git-submodules, refspec

We are using Gerrit for code review.
Gerrit stores reviewed code in non-standard reference path - `refs/changes`.
So, reference to commit looks like `refs/changes/95/295/2` .
I want to add project from Gerrit to my superproject as a submodule.

I can do it in two steps:

- add my project as a submodule to commit-hash currently pointed by master
- perform `git fetch origin refs/changes/95/295/2 && git checkout FETCH_HEAD` and commit the change.

But when I try to checkout my superproject and do `git update --init` git reports failure. Git can't find hash in submodule, because git didn't see references in `refs/changes` by default, and don't download objects from them.

Ok, I can fix it with executing `git config --add remote.origin.fetch '+refs/changes/*:refs/remotes/origin/changes/*'` in my gerrit repo, then retry submodule update, and that will be ok.

Question is, can I perform "add" and "init/update" submodule in one step as in usuial workflow? Basically, I need feature to set refspec before "clone"/"pull"/"submodule add"/"sumbodule update" execution start.

Comment: Finally I implement my own abstraction level on top of git. It works, and it's ugly. I'm not happy, but maybe I can fix git behaviour providing patch to Linus.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to push up a change with the submodule pointing to a commit at refs/changes.  Gerrit stores code there during review, but after the review is complete and the change has been submitted it can be accessed from the standard refs/heads/.  Your submodules should point to the reviewed & submitted code at refs/heads/BRANCH_NAME.

Comment: No, I want to do exactly this. I need to perform build with newly pushed changes, and I can build it as submodule in superproject.

Comment: In that case, the only option I'm aware of is to add the remote fetch spec as you indicated.  This is what our build-bots do at my job to verify unmerged changes.

Comment: Yep, I can add fetch-spec, but this will be additional step after `submodule update --init` failed. I can do it, but this is ugly, IMHO.